# Getting started with Socket IO - how to get response

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

so I want to use Flask Socket IO to emit a message to all clients, but im not sure on the javascript side how to call get the message

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hidden'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('test')
def test():
    print('test my event')
    socketio.emit('test response')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('test') }
    </script>
 

  </body>
  </html>
```

Pretty much, how do I get the response from socketio.emit('test response') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another socket.on() inside your script tag.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('test') }

        socket.on("test response", (response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    </script>
 

  </body>
  </html>
```

The socket.io calls are not necessarily sequential and hence you have as many `socket.on` as you need and based on what even is on the socket, the corresponding function will get triggered.

Hope it helps! Do ping me in the comments if you have any doubts still.

**--EDIT--**

Pointer to the docs for exact info on this.

https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#socket-on-eventName-callback

Comment: Still a bit confused, where is the response being stored with socket.on("test response", () => {});

Comment: Oh! that will passed as a parameter to your function that you provide. I will edit my code to show this change.